# What is the best time in a whole day for doing daily exercise like stretching, jogging, walking, cycling or swimming?

Tags: exercise

Is it more helpful to doing exercise in morning than evening? Or it doesn't matter when we do exercise in a whole day?

As far as I know, doing exercise immediately after meal is not a good idea but we can take a little walk after meal.

Up to what time interval we should not perform any intense exercise after or before meal?

Comment: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18/is-there-a-best-time-of-the-day-to-exercise/1036#1036 - Bottom line, it's really up to personal preference.

Comment: @JohnP the linked question is about boosting someone's metabolism - a read this question differently: the best time when you take various conditions into account. For example, I was told by my PE teacher a long time ago, that doing exercise in the evening is easier, because your muscles and joints have moved a little during the day (in the morning they are all stiff), and doing exercise in the morning helps reduce this stiffness. So perhaps the OP is looking for arguments on which they would base their decision/preference? @ OP - can you please specify if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: @Lucky - The question title is "Is there a best time of the day to exercise", with the addendum that it is for weight loss. In either case, the base answer there stands. It's personal preference, since in any exercise you should do some kind of warmup first, whether it's in the evening or some other time.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by the answers in [this question on fitness.se](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18/is-there-a-best-time-of-the-day-to-exercise/1036#1036), the best time of the day is whatever works best for you.

There is no magical time that will boost your metabolism more than other times, or anything like that. What most people are thinking of when they think of metabolism boosting is EPOC, or excess post-exercise oxygen consumption. This is commonly called the "afterburn" effect, which is where the body consumes more calories for an extended period after exercise sessions. The more intense the session, the higher the effect.

However, even with that, the amount of calories is low, in the 10-100 calories range over an extended period, as shown by the studies and math cited [in this article](http://www.unm.edu/~lkravitz/Article%20folder/epocarticle.html).

The best thing to do ([as suggested by the AHA](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/GettingHealthy/PhysicalActivity/When-Is-the-Best-Time-of-Day-to-Work-Out_UCM_438922_Article.jsp)) is to find a time that is most convenient and enjoyable for you, as you are far more likely to engage in the activity on a consistent basis, and being consistent is one of the best things you can do as far as exercise is concerned.

Comment: is it good to do hard exercise (like playing football) at midnight?

Comment: @Ooker - why not? If it fits your schedule, go for it. If it doesn't, then you might be tired the next day.